# Covering eyes when saying Shema Yisrael

Tags: minhag, shema, parts-of-the-body

When saying Kriyas Shema many have the custom of covering their eyes when saying Shema Yisrael. What is the reason this is done?

Answer (score 10):

> The Talmud (Berakhot 13b) is the original source for this custom. Here
>   there is a mention of Rabbi Judah the Prince covering his eyes while
>   he said the Shema to block out the distractions of the students around
>   him. This behavior was codified in the Shulhan Arukh (OH 61:4-5).

from http://www.myjewishlearning.com/ask_the_expert/at/Ask_the_Expert--Covered_eyes.shtml

see there for more reasons.
[chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1047775/jewish/Why-Do-We-Cover-Our-Eyes-for-Shema.htm) also has some good points on this.

Comment: I would note that the Gemara itself does not identify distractions of his students, as the cited text implies. (Unless I am missing something)

Comment: @Y  e  z There are different girsaos. The Ritva's girsa says Rebbe specifically covered his eyes, not just his face, and gives the reason mentioned in this answer.

Answer (score 6):

[Nefesh HaChaim](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%A9_%D7%94%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D) Shaar Gimmel Perek Beis(1):

> אבל אדון כל ית"ש הוא מלא את כל העולמות והנבראי' ואינם חוצצים חלילה נגדו יתב' כלל באמת. ואין עוד מלבדו ית' ממש שום דבר כלל בכל העולמות. מהעליון שבעליונים עד התהום התחתון שבתהומות הארץ. עד שתוכל לומר שאין כאן שום נברא ועולם כלל רק הכל מלא עצמות אחדותו הפשוט ית"ש.

Perek Gimmel(2):

> שאם ח"ו יקחנו לבנו לקבוע לנו מחשבה זו להתיר לעצמנו להתנהג גם במעשה לפי המחשבה זו. הלא יוכל להולד מזה ח"ו הריסת כמה יסודות התוה"ק ר"ל. ובנקל יוכל להלכד ח"ו ברשת היצר שיראה לו היתרא עפ"י מחשבה זו דרך משל להרהר בד"ת בשאט נפש אף במקומות המטונפי'. אחר שיוקבע אצלו תחלה שהכל אלהות גמור.
>
> ועוד כמה טעיות שיוכל לצא' ח"ו אם היה נקבע ההנהגה במעשה עפ"י זה הדרך

Perek Yud Aleph gloss(3):

> י"ל פנימיות כוונתם ז"ל היינו שאחר שיחדנוהו בפסוק שמע שהוא רק אחד אחדות פשוט ואין עוד מלבדו כלל וכל העולמות הם כאלו אינם במציאות כלל

Perek Yud Gimmel(4):

> א"ל משה אני נתעליתי יותר ממך שאתה ראית פני השכינה וכהו עינך כו' אבל אני הייתי מדבר עם השכינה פנים בפנים ולא כהו עיניו

Perek Yud Daled(5):

> אמנם מדרגת והשגת משרע"ה כפי שביארנו הוא ג"כ עצם ענין היחוד דתיבת אחד דק"ש

To summarize the above: The reality of existence is that the only true existence is Hashem, and it would be accurate to say that we don't really exist (1).  However, living with this awareness, or acting accordingly, would lead to major mistakes (2), and Hashem wants us to live according to our perception of existence.  The declaration of Krias Shema is the declaration of that truth, that Hashem is completely one and there is nothing else that truly exists (3).  Moshe, who was on the level to perceive that truth which is expressed in Krias Shema(5), spoke to Hashem face to face and *his eyes* did not dim(4).

My conclusion based on the above: We cover our eyes because we are confronting a reality and truth with which we cannot function in this world.  Moshe was able to look with his eyes because he could handle that perception.