# Why do we cover our eyes during Shema?

Tags: minhag, tefilla, shema

There is a very widespread custom to cover one's eyes with one's hand during the first pasuk of Keriyas Shema. Where/when did this custom originate, and what is the reason for it?

Comment: there's a chasam sofer and a kli yakar on this, but I don't have time to write it up myself and was hoping to find earlier sources

Comment: (the kli yakar is on this week's parsha (balak), which is why I remembered to ask this now)

Comment: בר פחתי בשעה שמעביר ידיו על פניו מקבל עליו עול מלכות שמים

Comment: @shmuelbrin why?

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35987/759

Comment: @msh210 Oops sorry I didn't find it when I searched. Should I delete the question?

Comment: No need. People who search the site using search terms in this question which don't appear in the other will find this one and thus the other.