# Covering eyes when saying Shema for children

Tags: children-parenting, shema, see-sight-vision-blind, sleep

When a child is too young to say the bed-time Shema for himself, the custom is that parents say it for them as they go to bed.

Should the parent cover their own eyes, the child's eyes, or perhaps neither (or both, but I assume not)?

Comment: Someone can remove the children-parenting tag if it doesn't apply

Comment: there is no halocho to cover your eyes in the jamoro or rambam. it is not a must just like a kippo is not not a halocho

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob And therefore...

Comment: Its meant for concentration so the one who is saying it should do it

Comment: @sam [is it](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35987/covering-eyes-when-saying-shema-yisrael/35991#35991)?

Comment: Yes I would go with the gemmaras pshat of Rabbi Yehuda on this one

Comment: @YEZ yes covering eyes is if u you have trouble concentrating. if you dont have that problem concentrating on what you say there is no reason to do so. _edited for tone_

Comment: @sam which gemara's pshat are you referring to?

Answer (score 3):

As I recall from when my children were the age you imply (40 years ago) I would cover my eyes and the child would imitate me by covering his or her own eyes. Since they were learning by saying it with me, it was part of teaching them. I do not recall a specific psak. It did not take long for them to learn what to do.